# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "wpdb" not found in load.php

Tags: php, wordpress

After updated php version to 8.1 in Wordpress, i can't show admin login and errors are:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "wpdb" not found in /home/mhd-01/www.xxxxxxxx.it/htdocs/wp-includes/load.php:428 Stack trace: #0 /home/mhd-01/www.xxxxxxxx.it/htdocs/wp-settings.php(120): require_wp_db() #1 /home/mhd-01/www.xxxxxxxx.it/htdocs/wp-config.php(98): require_once('...') #2 /home/mhd-01/www.xxxxxxxx.it/htdocs/wp-load.php(37): require_once('...') #3 /home/mhd-01/www.xxxxxxxx.it/htdocs/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('...') #4 /home/mhd-01/www.xxxxxxxx.it/htdocs/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/mhd-01/www.xxxxxxxx.it/htdocs/wp-includes/load.php on line 428

Is there any ideas about can i resolve this? Thanks.

I would login and not show any errors in my site on Wordpress.

Comment: What Wordpress version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the WordPress core files are not damaged or corrupted. A missing or malformed file can sometimes cause class loading issues. You should think about re-uploading the core WordPress files to maintain their integrity. Check that you copied the wp-content folder and replaced it with the new one.